# Algorithm to edit a complex line in a 2D- Array needed

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix, multidimensional-array, geometry

**Short intro:** I am working on a 3D laserscanning device, that creates a point cloud using pictures of an object which is illuminated by the laser.

Each picture shows essentially a line which represents the objects surface. 
What I do then is store the value of brightness of each pixel in a 2D Array, which in the end results in a Matrix that puts a number on the position of the illuminated line. This I can take to further calculate the point cloud. All of this I'm doing in C++.

**Now to the problem at hand:**

After storing the brightness information inside the matrix, I get a complex line which is several pixels thick (thickness not uniform). I need it to be exactly 1 Pixel wide. Up until now I calculated either the mean value of the line, or used a weight function.

This only works well as long as your line mostly runs vertically or horizontally throughout the picture/matrix, because you can calculate the right value for each seperate line or column.

I have now pictures/matrices where the line has a more complex shape, so these simple solutions won't work anymore. Here are two examples:

[image: Pic1]
[image: Pic2]

How can I calculate the mean value or put a weight function on these lines, so i can bring them down to a thickness of 1px? I need an algorithm that does this automatically because I have sets of hundreds of pictures, where this line can be differently shaped, so it would be too timeconsuming/impossible to edit all of them seperately.

I hope I somehow talked sense rather then complicate things ;)

Comment: is it always a line or can it be a curve?

Comment: It can also be curved. The curves themselves shouldn't be such a big problem though. The way I see it, the biggest problem is when the "line" itself changes orientations too much over it's course, so you can't apply a singular approach anymore (like calculating from top to bottom, or left to right - as I also briefly described in my question)

Comment: Just extract the points where the direction changes -- that should give you a line string. From then on, you could even recompute another image with the line width you desire, or simply store it as a geometric primitive.
Also, it seems your pattern creates lines that are perpendicular to each other. you could very well evaluate the angle, rotate the image and do whatever processing you use to do, as said in the OP.

Comment: Treat the pixels of the piece-wise line segments as point clouds and find the linear least squares fitting line for each segment. Then "shrink" the thicker lines to the fitted lines.

Comment: I realise I made a poor choise regarding my exemplary pictures. Those visible lines are usually curved, or have minor dents in them at least, which describe the objects surface in particular places - so they are very important in the computation of the point cloud. Therefore i can not use a linear fitting or just replace the measured curve with a straight line, because I would lose the information of the objects surface. Nevertheless the idea to make a fitting is something to consider, it wouldn't be a linear fitting though. Thanks for sharing your thoughts :)

Comment: You seem to be looking for [morphological thinning](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/thin.htm).